# create MVC in nodejs mysql without using sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, model-view-controller

I am new on node js and trying on MVC patterns. I saw many node js with MySQL applying to sequalize. but I want to make my own MVC framework because I have created a get, insert, update delete function dynamic in db.js which works fine.

Route.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const tutorialController = require(`${process.cwd()}/src/modules/tutorials/tutorial.controller`);
router.get("/", tutorialController.index);
router.post("/", tutorialController.create);
router.get("/:id", tutorialController.show);
router.put("/:id", tutorialController.update);

module.exports = router;
```

controller.js

```
const Tutorial = require(`${process.cwd()}/src/modules/tutorials/tutorial.model`);

const index = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tutorial = await Tutorial.get();
    if (tutorial) {
      return res.status(200).send(tutorial);
    } else {
      return res.status(404).send({ error: "No Data found" });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send(e.toString());
  }
};
```

and model

```
const db = require(`${process.cwd()}/src/config/db.config`);

// constructor
const Tutorial = (title, description, published) => {
  this.title = title;
  this.description = description;
  this.published = published;
};
const table = "tutorials";
db.model = table;

Tutorial.get = () => {
  console.log(db.model)
  return db.get();
//i don't want to pass return db.get('tablename'); if I pass, I can get the table name in db.js and it works; I want the db.js to get the table based on models table like db.model="tbl_tutorials"

};
```

db.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");


const creds = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_SCHEMA,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  multipleStatements: false
};

const openConnection = mysql.createPool(creds);
const model = models => {


models;
};


exports.escape = str => openConnection.escape(str);
exports.creds = creds;
    exports.get = (model, fields = "*", condition = "1=1") => {

  

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("i am inside get" + model);

    // build the query string
    let qryStr = "select" + fields + "from " + model + " where " + condition;

    openConnection.query(qryStr, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        //console.log(results)
        resolve(results);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

In this case, every time I have to write SQL code in the model, I would like to make a model which only has table information and can be accessed by the controller and want the controller to write the getAll function from db.js to controller getting the table info directly from the model.
I am waiting for a response.